# Google Sheets equivalent for Excel's AGGREGAT formula

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am using Google Sheets and I need to implement following excel formula into my sheet.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1XzAYEezt2gNt_tdbxyZT-p6XwjNdhvUbt_9rBoABlhI/edit?usp=sharing

```
 =IFERROR(INDEX(Formularantworten!B:B;AGGREGAT(15;6;ROW(Formularantworten!$B$2:$B$100)/(Formularantworten!$B$2:$B$100<>"")/(Formularantworten!$H$2:$H$100<>"");ROW(A1)));"")
```

Answer (score 0):

Well if you want to match two columns and index a third column, finding the first match, you can do what you used to do in Excel before  Aggregate came along:

```
=index(C:C,match(1,(A:A<>"")*(B:B<>""),0))
```

or

```
=index(C:C,min(if((A:A<>"")*(B:B<>""),row(A:A))))
```

But in Google sheets you have more options and are more likely to use something like

```
=query(A:C,"select C where A is not null and B is not null limit 1")
```